# Disable enter/return and go on ipads/iphones from submitting ajax forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, ipad

I have searched here and found 3 or 4 articles asking the same question and have tried all their answers, however either i'm doing something very wrong or its the fact im using ajax in my jquery to submit the forms. But basically i would like to disable Enter/Return keys on keyboard and the Go button on ipads on my forms. below is an example of a form im using

```
<form class="widget-header rooms">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Room name" name="roomName[]" class="form-input add-room-input input-width-xxlarge">
    <input type="hidden" class="roomId" name="roomId[]">
    <input type="hidden" class="inventoryId" name="inventoryId[]" value="<?=$_GET['inventory_id']?>">
    <div class="toolbar no-padding">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <span class="btn saveRoom"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save Room</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the javascript functions etc

```
$('body').on('click', '.saveRoom', function(e) {
    postFormRooms($(this).closest('form.rooms').get(0));
});

// This script saves the room name
    function postFormRooms(form) {
        var $this = $(form);
        var string = $this.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/add_room.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                var saveIcon = $this.find('.add-room-input');
                $this.find('.roomId').val(data);
                $this.siblings('.toolbar-small').children().children('.addItem').fadeIn();
                $this.siblings('.toolbar-small').children().children('.dropdown-toggle').fadeIn();
                $this.parent().attr('data-parent-room', data);
                saveIcon.addClass('savedField').delay(1000).queue(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('savedField');
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, i just need to disable those buttons and i can't get it to work. You can see that im not using submit buttons or anything as i am using icons to trigger the functions. Is this causing my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your code.

```
<script>
    $(".widget-header").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Ah! I popped it in a document.ready function and it works for the input that is there when the page loads. however the dynamically added forms that follow the same suit don't listen to this, any ideas?

Comment: I have also tried it at the end of the document and its the same result, dynamically added ones fail

Comment: i fixed it!
$('body').on('submit', '.rooms, .item', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Thanks, simple fix! Sorry @jcamax my error in the first place, your suggestion is spot on

Comment: You can try changing the selector from  $(".widget-header") to $("form"), but it only works if the form exist in the dom, if you need to prevent submit in forms created dynamically you need to call the script just after been created the form. ok?